# SQL: Get row with highest ID, but if specific column is filled, get that row

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table called vouchers with many voucher codes inside. This is how the table looks like, with a few dummy data.

```
+-------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| gs_id |  code   |   domain    |   start    |    ende    |
+-------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1    | EXAMPLE | example.com | 1288263600 | 1291330740 |
|  2    | NULL    | example.com | 1288604942 | 1293750000 |
|  3    | ABC123  | second.com  | 1288604952 | 1298847600 |
|  4    | 456XYZ  | second.com  | 0          | 1288303200 |
+-------+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Now i need an SQL statement which returns me:

1) Only one *id* per *domain*
2) If there are multiple entries per *domain* it should return the row with the highest *id*

That is already working with that Query:

```
SELECT MAX(gs_id) AS id,domain FROM vouchers WHERE start >= 0 AND start <= 1288263600 AND (ende = 0  || ende > 1418046119) GROUP BY domain
```

But i have one exception which is important to me:

If there are multiple entries  for one *domain* and the column *code* of the entry with highest id is empty, AND there is one other voucher from that domain with non empty column *code* it should return that row.. If there are multiple rows which non empty code column it should here also return the row with highest gs_id

In my example ie expect that these rows are returned:

```
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id |  code   |   domain    |   start    |    ende    |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | EXAMPLE | example.com | 1288263600 | 1291330740 | because of code,
|  4 | 456XYZ  | second.com  | 1288604958 | 1288303200 | because of MAX(id)
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Row 2 should not be choosed because it has empty column *code* and there is another entry from same *domein* which has a non empty code.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the `null` code rows in the derived table and get the max gs_id. Then `join` the result to the main table.

```
select t.id, t.domain, v.code, v.start, v.ende
from (SELECT MAX(gs_id) AS id, domain 
      FROM vouchers 
      WHERE start >= 0 AND start <= 1288263600 AND (ende = 0  or ende > 1418046119) 
      and code is not null
      GROUP BY domain) t
join vouchers v on t.domain = v.domain and t.id = v.gs_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it on our live table. But if there are multiple entries for one domain it only shows the row with highes gs_id, which my query is already doing. But i am looking for some condition: If there is any row where field code is not null, then show that row (if there are multiple with non empty code, show the one with the highest gs_id) and only if there are rows without valid code show the row with highes gs_id

Comment: did you even look at the query to understand? you only wanted the row with the highest gs_id. If code is null for that row, you needed the next highest gs_id row where gs_id is not null. And that is what the query does

Comment: THANKS i found the mistake.. code was not NULL but it was "".. so i changed that.. but now the query is not returning any row with empty code but i know that there are some.. (num rows is now: 2158) with my original query it's 3580..